# Bug in DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a blank workbook in Excel
2. Page Layout tab --> [Print Titles] button --> Rows to repeat at top: `$1:$1`
3. Save (in .xlsx format) and close workbook
4. Open MS Access
5. Export any table or query to the workbook we just saved:

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "TempQry", "C:\Book1.xlsx"`

6. Open Book1.xlsx and click on Print Preview for Sheet1
7. Print preview shows the following error message: **"Print preview is not available."**
8. Click on Page Setup then switch to Sheet tab: **Rows to repeat at top:** is blank

Why is Print Preview unavailable and why is the "Rows to repeat at top" box blank?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Access.  I'm not sure why it's happening, but I did find proof that it is a bug.

For proof, repeat the steps to reproduce from above.  After Step 3, right-click Book1.xlsx and choose 7-zip --> Open archive... (requires 7-zip, obviously).  Open folder "xl" inside the archive then open the workbook.xml file.

Notice the following text in the xml file:

```
<definedName name="_xlnm.Print_Titles" localSheetId="0">Sheet1!$1:$1</definedName>
```

Now close the 7-zip archive and continue with the steps from above.  After step 5, re-open the Book1.xlsx via 7-zip --> Open archive...  Open xl\workbook.xml and notice that the text above has been changed to:

```
<definedName name="_xlnm.Print_Titles" localSheetId="0">'Sheet1'!$A$1:$IV$1</definedName>
```

In other words, MS Access made some effort to...standardize?...the workbook's defined names.  To do this it added columns to a rows-only range (`$1:$1` --> `$A$1:$IV$1`).

The same thing happens if you set columns to repeat at left: (`$A:$A` --> `$A$1:$A$1048576`).

Interestingly, if you declare both rows to repeat at top and columns to repeat at left, the bug is avoided:

```
<definedName name="_xlnm.Print_Titles" localSheetId="0">Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$1:$1</definedName>
```

---

**Workarounds:**

- Set both "Rows to repeat at top" and "Columns to repeat at left" or
- Use another method to transfer to Excel, such as [`CopyFromRecordset()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240%28v=office.15%29.aspx)